# How to check units?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, units, coulombs-law

I've got: $Q=\frac{Er^2}{k}$
how to check the units?
I start with $\left[\frac{\text V}{\text m} \,  \text m^2\right]$, tried replacing $[ \text V ]$ with $\left[ \frac{\text J}{\text C} \right]$, but it's not leading me to $[\text C]$.

Comment: please note that you can use LateX on this website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all note that $k$ is not dimensionless, it is $k = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}$, and $\varepsilon_0$ has dimensions of $\frac{ \text C^2}{ \text {N m}^2}$. So you have already $\frac{ \text{V C}^2 \text m^2}{ \text {N m m} ^2}$. Also, *volt* can be expanded as $ \text V = \frac{ \text {N m}}{ \text C}$, so one gets
$$ \frac{ \text C^2}{ \text {N m}^2} = \frac{ \text{V C}^2\text { m}^2}{ \text {N m m}^2} = \frac{ \text C^2}{ \text {N m}} \frac{ \text {N m}}{ \text C} = \text C$$
- exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, break everything down into a set of indivisible units: kilograms, meters, seconds, and coulombs.  So ask yourself what is a joule in terms of those units, and also consider that the constant $k$ has units.  You can figure out what those units are by writing out Coulomb's law.

Edit: the units of $\epsilon_0$ can be found as follows.  You know Coulomb's law.

$$E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q}{r^2}$$

Rearrange this to solve for $\epsilon_0$:

$$\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi E} \frac{q}{r^2}$$

You know that $E$ is measured as force per unit charge.  The other quantities are charges and lengths (or dimensionless constants).  The result is

$$\epsilon_0 = \frac{\text{[charge]}^2}{\text{[force]} \times \text{[length]}^2}$$

Comment: it seems k is just a number (4, pi and epsilons). Am I right?

Comment: No, $k$ has units because $\epsilon_0$ has units.  Do a dimensional analysis of Coulomb's law and you will see what these units are.

Comment: k is F/m, right?

Comment: That's $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: ok, but the rest is just numbers (I mean 4, pi, epsilon r)?

Comment: See my edit, Tom. $r$ is a length, usually measured in meters.